# Android App Bluetooth Logcat NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

I am getting NullPointerException error on LogCat messages, and I'm having trouble finding the issue.

According to the LogCat messages, the problem started from the line 93, which:

```
// Get a set of currently paired devices
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

My code and the logcat messages are attached bellow:

```
package android.mgo.helloandroid;

import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BTDdetecetwithV7Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    // Debugging
   private static final String Tag="Messages";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Return Intent extra
   // public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (D) Log.d(Tag, "in onCreate()");
        if (D) Log.e(Tag, "onCreate()");
        if (D) Log.i(Tag, "onCreate()");
        // Setup the window


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        // Set result CANCELED in case the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        if (D) Log.i(Tag, "in setResult()");
        // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
        // one for newly discovered devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main);


        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (D) Log.e(Tag, "On line 87");


        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);

        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);


        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get a set of currently paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();


        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (D) Log.d(Tag, "in the doDiscovery()");

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }

        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }


        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {
        //if (D) Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");
        //if (D) Log.e(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);


        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }



        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }
        // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
        // changes the title when discovery is finished
        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();



            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }

            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

}


**the main.xml:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_paired_devices"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>


   <ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />  

 <TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_other_devices"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

 <ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="2" /> 



   <Button android:id="@+id/button_scan"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_scan"
    />


</LinearLayout>

Manifest file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.mgo.helloandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".BTDdetecetwithV7Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
</manifest>

 - **And the logcat is:**


03-03 18:41:51.616: D/Messages(209): in onCreate()
03-03 18:41:51.637: E/Messages(209): onCreate()
03-03 18:41:51.637: I/Messages(209): onCreate()
03-03 18:41:51.897: I/Messages(209): in setResult()
03-03 18:41:51.976: E/Messages(209): On line 87
03-03 18:41:52.026: D/AndroidRuntime(209): Shutting down VM
03-03 18:41:52.057: W/dalvikvm(209): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-03 18:41:52.136: E/AndroidRuntime(209): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.mgo.helloandroid/android.mgo.helloandroid.BTDdetecetwithV7Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.mgo.helloandroid.BTDdetecetwithV7Activity.onCreate(BTDdetecetwithV7Activity.java:93)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-03 18:41:52.166: E/AndroidRuntime(209):  ... 11 more
03-03 18:41:52.226: I/dalvikvm(209): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-03 18:41:52.246: I/dalvikvm(209): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 18:46:52.267: I/Process(209): Sending signal. PID: 209 SIG: 9
```

Any guesses whatsoever as to what is going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently your mBtAdapter is `null`. Are you testing this on an emulator?

Comment: yes i am, on Windows 7 64bit...

Comment: and i tried it on Android 2.1 and 2.2 (On emulator) and it's pointing to the same line...

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your application on a real device, the emulators don't support bluetooth.

Comment: i know, but not all of them, the emulators on Linux 2.4, so that's why i did try it on Oracle VirtualBox on both Linux 2.4 and Linux others...however i tried it on HTC Hero as well, but it crashes giving "Unexpected error..." message.